# Why can't I find certain questions just using tags?

Tags: bug, questions, locked-questions, tag-search

I am looking for the best questions that have both the tags [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [ide](/questions/tagged/ide).

I get back a [list of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide+php?sort=votes&pagesize=50) sorted by votes. Why wasn't [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116292/what-is-the-best-ide-for-php) returned to me, this was the one I was looking for and I could not find it. Why didn't it appear? Is it because it is a Wiki? If so, how am I supposed to find it?

**EDIT:** The reason this bothers me slightly is because this question is actually [linked to on the PHP wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) in the IDE section. Reading it once and then looking for it on SO and not finding it is quite disconcerting! If it is considered a useless question, ***why is it linked***?

Comment: @Mat thanks, exactly what i needed. Is there no way to find them except by search then?

Comment: Mark the ones you like as favorites, or use your browser's bookmarks. Only directed searches will work for finding them.

Answer (score 1):

Why not search for the tags and the word "best": [[php] [ide] best](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bide%5D+best)

*And it's the top result!*

Also "best ide for php" gives this post [top in Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=best+ide+for+php), and has the benefit of keeping a cached result (or finding the result elsewhere)... should this question eventually get deleted.